# Problems trying to calculate FWHM with scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am having problems trying to find the FWHM of some data. I initially tried to fit a curve using `interpolate.interp1d`. With this I was able to create a function that when I entered an x value it would return an interpolated y value. The issue is that I need the inverse of this functionality. In other words, I want to switch my independent and dependent variables. When I try to switch them, I get errors because the independent data has to be sorted. If I sort the data, I will lose the indexes, and therefore lose the shape of my graph.

I tried:

```
x = np.linspace(0, line.shape[0], line.shape[0])
self.x_curve = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, 'linear')
```

where `y` is my data.

To get the inverse, I tried:

```
self.x_curve = interpolate.interp1d(sorted(y), x, 'linear')
```

but the values are off.

I then moved on and tried to use UnivariateSpline and get the roots to find the FWHM (from this question here: [Finding the full width half maximum of a peak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582795/finding-the-full-width-half-maximum-of-a-peak)), but the roots() method keeps giving me an empty list `[]`.

This is what I used:

```
x_curve = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y)
r = x_curve.roots()
print(r)
```

Here is an image of the data (with the UnivariateSpline):

[image: Data plot]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `UnivariateSpline.roots()` to get FWHM will only work if you shift the data so that its value is 0 at FWHM.

Seeing that the background of the data is noisy, I'd first estimate the baseline. For example:

```
y_baseline = y[(x<200) & (x>350)].mean()
```

(adjust the limits for `x` as you see fit). Then shift the data so that the middle of the baseline and the peak is at 0. Seeing that your data has a minimum and not a maximum as in the example, I'm using `y.min()`:

```
y_shifted = y - (y.min()+y_baseline)/2.0
```

Now fit a spline to this shifted data and `roots()` should be able to find the roots, the difference of which is the FWHM.

```
x_curve = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y_shifted, s=0)
x_curve.roots()
```

Increase the `s` parameter if you want to estimate the FWHM from smoothed data.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This what I tried, but I am still not getting the roots: `x = np.linspace(0, line.shape[0], line.shape[0], False)
        x = map(int, x)
        y_baseline = y[(x<200) & (x>350)].mean()
        y_shifted = y - (y.min() + y_baseline)/2.0    curve = interpolate.UnivariateSpline(x, y_shifted, s=0)
        r = curve.roots()
        print(r)` I am still getting an empty list. The curve shifted down to below zero.

Comment: Nevermind, the min function had some conflict with numpy and wasn't working correctly. I fixed it and I am now getting the roots. Thanks for your help!