# Inconsistent results from extracting rotated 1d profiles from 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, interpolation

I have a 2D numpy array that represents an image (see below).[image: Central PSF for band 3: http://wise2.ipac.caltech.edu/docs/release/allsky/expsup/sec4_4c.html#rchisqind]

The elliptical object in the image is rotated an angle `theta` from the vertical y-axis. In my code, I'd like to measure the FWHM of the object at various positions (including through the one that will be maximized, the semi-major axis at angle `theta`).

To do this, I've used techniques from both of these questions (to extract the line at a given angle, and then use UnivariateSpline to compute the FWHM given a 1d profile): [How to extract an arbitrary line of values from a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878398/how-to-extract-an-arbitrary-line-of-values-from-a-numpy-array) and [Finding the full width half maximum of a peak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582795/finding-the-full-width-half-maximum-of-a-peak)

However, I've noticed that my results are inconsistent. If I extract a profile at a given angle from the entire image (which is a (641, 641) array), I get a different result for the FWHM than if I get the profile at the same angle out of a (100,100) subimage where the object is centered. I realize that since the method involves interpolation, I will likely get different values along the profiles. But what I need is a reliable and consistent way to compute these FWHMs, and the angle at which it is maximized (since right now it's giving me a different angle for subimage vs whole image). Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline

def profiles(image, theta):
    max_y, max_x = np.where(image==1) #the image has been normalized so that the highest intensity point=1
    max_y, max_x = max_y[0], max_x[0]

    subimage = image[max_y-50:max_y+50, max_x-50:max_x+50] # now the maximum is exactly centered at (50, 50)

    # Set up to extract profiles (do two legs to ensure it passes through centroid)
    x_maj_1, y_maj_1 = 50-50*np.tan(theta), 0
    mid_x, mid_y = 50, 50
    x_maj_2, y_maj_2 = 50+50*np.tan(theta), 99

    # Form axes
    length_maj = int(round(np.hypot(x_maj_2-x_maj_1, y_maj_2-y_maj_1)))
    x1, y1 = np.linspace(x_maj_1, mid_x, length_maj//2), np.linspace(y_maj_1, mid_y, length_maj//2)
    x2, y2 = np.linspace(mid_x, x_maj_2, length_maj//2)[1:], np.linspace(mid_y, y_maj_2, length_maj//2)[1:]

    # Concatenate legs
    x_maj = np.concatenate((x1, x2), axis=0)
    y_maj = np.concatenate((y1, y2), axis=0)

    # Get profile
    z_maj = subimage[y_maj.astype(np.int), x_maj.astype(np.int)]
    return z_maj

def interpolate_width(axis):
    half_max = 1/2
    x = np.arange(0, len(axis))
    spline = UnivariateSpline(x, axis-half_max, s=0)
    r1, r2 = spline.roots()
    return r2-r1 #FWHM in pixel units
```

Now, to find the angle from the y-axis at which the FWHM is maximized:

```
thetas = np.arange(0, 45, 0.5)
widths = []
for theta in thetas:
    theta = np.deg2rad(theta)
    z = profiles(image, theta)
    width = interpolate_width(z)
    widths.append(width)

fwhm_maj = max(widths)
angle_arg = np.array(widths).argmax()
angle_max = thetas[angle_arg]
print('Maximized FWHM and associated position angle:', fwhm_maj, angle_max)
```

Outputs: `Maximized FWHM and associated position angle: 20.899 14.5`

From the information on the website I linked, the pixel scale of the image is 0.275 arcseconds. So multiplying by that, the FWHM should at its maximum at a position angle of 14.5 degrees, with a value of about 5.75 arcseconds. However, Table 1 on the website clearly states that the maximized position angle from the y-axis is only 6 degrees, and that the FWHM of the major axis there is 7.36 arcseconds. So something must be wrong here.

And if I run this code again but on the whole image instead of a subimage, I get a completely different result for the angle and the FWHM. Does anyone know how I can find a more consistent (and accurate) method? Thank you!

Comment: you might be getting some issues with setting your mid at `max_y, max_x = max_y[0], max_x[0]` - what if there is a circle of pixels that have all hit 1 - you will be taking the upper left of the circle as your center.

Comment: That's true, but for now since I'm only running the code on this image there isn't an issue (I printed the `np.where` statement to test it and it's just one x-coordinate and one y-coordinate).

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but you seem to snap your line coordinates to the pixel grid which feels pretty inaccurate to me. Also, the "inverted letterbox" (white bars) might confuse your program? Maybe it would be safer to use proper 2D interpolation and clip the image, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage, interpolate, optimize

img = ndimage.io.imread('VJQwQ.png')
# b&w
img = img[..., 0]
# cut "white letterbox"
img = img[:, np.where(np.any(img!=255, axis=0))[0]]

# setup interpolator for off grid pixel values
x, y = img.shape
x, y = (np.arange(z) - (z-1)/2 for z in (x, y))
intr = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x, y, img, kx=3, ky=3)
s = np.arange(-50, 51)

# setup line sections
# for simplicity we assume the peak is in the center
def at_angle(phi):
    def f(s, shift=0):
        x, y = np.cos(phi)*s, np.sin(phi)*s
        return intr(x, y, grid=False) - shift
    return f

# example
phi = np.pi/3
f = at_angle(phi)
mx = f(0)
left = optimize.brentq(f, -50, 0, (mx/2,))
right = optimize.brentq(f, 0, 50, (mx/2,))

# plot it
from matplotlib import pylab
pylab.plot(s, f(s))
pylab.plot([left, left], [0, mx])
pylab.plot([right, right], [0, mx])
pylab.plot([-50, 50], [mx/2, mx/2])
pylab.savefig('tst.png')
```

[image]

Comment: What is the significance of the 255 (`img!=255`)? I'm not sure what you mean by "white letterbox", so I don't know how I'd apply this line to my image (if I try your code here it becomes `img[:, 0]` which then returns `IndexError: too many indices for array`)

Comment: @curious_cosmo I meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_%28filming%29), only in the image you posted the bars are white and vertical. A horizontal section through the entire image would have its maximal values at both its ends, not in the center. If we try applying a bracketing root finder starting with the center and the last or first point it obviously doesn't work in this situation. That's why I suggested cutting the white bars off would do no harm. It is not clear to me how you are getting to `img[:, 0]`.

Comment: @curious_cosmo Anyway,  as we later restrict the section to 50 pixels around the center, you can simply omit the line containing `img != 255`. I tried and it still works for me.

Comment: @curious_cosmo re the `img[:, 0]`. Is the `img` you are starting with `MxNx3` or just `MxN`? If it is `MxN` then the error you are getting comes from the line after `# b&w` and you should omit that instead.

Comment: Yes, my starting image is just `MxN`. Also, I'm not sure why the white bars appear here, but my actual image doesn't have them (I checked in ds9). For some reason following your code I cannot get the same vertical lines to show up through the half max -- instead, they appear as diagonal lines cutting through each other in the center.

Comment: @curious_cosmo hm, that's weird. What values do you get for left, right and mx? What are their types?