# Ploting multiple Gaussians from pandas file

Tags: python, gaussian

I am trying to plot multiple gaussians on one plot with different heights, widths and centers from this type of dataframe:

| hight(y) | fwhM(width) | centers(x) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24.122348 | 1.827472 | 98 |
| 24.828252 | 4.333549 | 186 |
| 26.810812 | 1.728494 | 276 |
| 25.997897 | 1.882424 | 373 |
| 24.503944 | 2.222210 | 471 |
| 27.488572 | 1.750039 | 604 |
| 31.556823 | 3.844592 | 683 |
| 27.920951 | 0.891394 | 792 |
| 27.009054 | 1.917744 | 897 |

Any idea on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

We will reuse the Gaussian plotter as defined in

- [Creating gaussians of fixed width and std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66961195/creating-gaussians-of-fixed-width-and-std/66987465?noredirect=1#comment118620211_66987465)

(The code is repeated here)

#### Data

The following code generates the above dataframe.

```
data = [
    (24.122348, 1.827472, 98),
    (24.828252, 4.333549, 186),
    (26.810812, 1.728494, 276),
    (25.997897, 1.882424, 373),
    (24.503944, 2.222210, 471),
    (27.488572, 1.750039, 604),
    (31.556823, 3.844592, 683),
    (27.920951, 0.891394, 792),
    (27.009054, 1.917744, 897),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["height", "fwhm", "center"])
```

#### Gaussian

Taken from the reference post above.

```
import matplotlib.cm as mpl_cm
import matplotlib.colors as mpl_colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist


class Gaussian:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.center = np.array(self.size) / 2
        self.axis = self._calculate_axis()

    def _calculate_axis(self):
        """
            Generate a list of rows, columns over multiple axis.

            Example:
                Input: size=(5, 3)
                Output: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([[0], [1], [2]])]
        """
        axis = [np.arange(size).reshape(-1, *np.ones(idx, dtype=np.uint8))
                for idx, size in enumerate(self.size)]
        return axis

    def update_size(self, size):
        """ Update the size and calculate new centers and axis.  """
        self.size = size
        self.center = np.array(self.size) / 2
        self.axis = self._calculate_axis()

    def create(self, dim=1, fwhm=3, center=None):
        """ Generate a gaussian distribution on the center of a certain width.  """
        center = center if center is not None else self.center[:dim]
        distance = sum((ax - ax_center) ** 2 for ax_center, ax in zip(center, self.axis))
        distribution = np.exp(-4 * np.log(2) * distance / fwhm ** 2)
        return distribution

    def creates(self, dim=2, fwhm=3, centers: np.ndarray = None):
        """ Combines multiple gaussian distributions based on multiple centers.  """
        centers = np.array(centers or np.array([self.center]).T).T
        indices = np.indices(self.size).reshape(dim, -1).T

        distance = np.min(cdist(indices, centers, metric='euclidean'), axis=1)
        distance = np.power(distance.reshape(self.size), 2)

        distribution = np.exp(-4 * np.log(2) * distance / fwhm ** 2)
        return distribution

    @staticmethod
    def plot(distribution, show=True):
        """ Plotter, in case you do not know the dimensions of your distribution, or want the same interface.  """
        if len(distribution.shape) == 1:
            return Gaussian.plot1d(distribution, show)
        if len(distribution.shape) == 2:
            return Gaussian.plot2d(distribution, show)
        if len(distribution.shape) == 3:
            return Gaussian.plot3d(distribution, show)
        raise ValueError(f"Trying to plot {len(distribution.shape)}-dimensional data, "
                         f"Only 1D, 2D, and 3D distributions are valid.")

    @staticmethod
    def plot1d(distribution, show=True, vmin=None, vmax=None, cmap=None):
        norm = mpl_colors.Normalize(
                vmin=vmin if vmin is not None else distribution.min(),
                vmax=vmax if vmin is not None else distribution.max()
        )
        cmap = mpl_cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap or mpl_cm.get_cmap('jet'))
        cmap.set_array(distribution)
        c = [cmap.to_rgba(value) for value in distribution]  # defines the color

        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        ax.scatter(np.arange(len(distribution)), distribution, c=c)
        ax.plot(distribution)

        fig.colorbar(cmap)
        if show: plt.show()
        return fig

    @staticmethod
    def plot2d(distribution, show=True):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        img = ax.imshow(distribution, cmap='jet')
        fig.colorbar(img)
        if show: plt.show()
        return fig

    @staticmethod
    def plot3d(distribution, show=True):
        m, n, c = distribution.shape
        x, y, z = np.mgrid[:m, :n, :c]
        out = np.column_stack((x.ravel(), y.ravel(), z.ravel(), distribution.ravel()))
        x, y, z, values = np.array(list(zip(*out)))

        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

        # Standalone colorbar, directly creating colorbar on fig results in strange artifacts.
        img = ax.scatter([0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], c=[0, 1], cmap=mpl_cm.get_cmap('jet'))
        img.set_visible = False
        fig.colorbar(img)

        ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=values, cmap=mpl_cm.get_cmap('jet'))
        if show: plt.show()
        return fig
```

#### Solution

Since it is unclear to me how you want to the Gaussian distributions to interact when they are in part of multiple widths, I will assume that you want the maximum value.

Then the main logic is that we can now generate a unique Gaussian distribution for every center with given full width half maximum (fwhm), and take the maximum of all the distrubutions.

```
distribution = np.zeros((1200,))

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["height", "fwhm", "center"])
gaussian = Gaussian(size=distribution.shape)

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    distribution = np.maximum(distribution, gaussian.create(fwhm=row.fwhm, center=[row.center]))

gaussian.plot(distribution, show=True)
```

#### Result

[image: Merged Multi Gaussian distribution]

---

### Edit

Since the question now asks for a different distribution, you can adjust the code in the `create` (and `creates`) method with the following to get different types of distributions:

```
def create(self, dim=1, fwhm=3, center=None):
    """ Generate a gaussian distribution on the center of a certain width.  """
    center = center if center is not None else self.center[:dim]
    distance = sum((ax - ax_center) for ax_center, ax in zip(center, self.axis))
    distribution = sps.beta.pdf(distance / max(distance), a=3, b=100)
    return distribution
```

Where `sps.beta` comes from `import scipy.stats as sps`, and can be changed with a gamma distribution as well. e.g. `distribution = sps.gamma.pdf(distance, 10, 40)`.

Note that the distance is no longer squared, and that the argument `fwhm`, could be replaced by the parameters required for the distribution.

Comment: I added what the signal I am emulating would look like [link](https://imgur.com/l1ELdo5) a Gaussian was a crud estimate, and I am guessing a better function would be better. The highs in the Gaussian doesn't seem to vary in that plot. Could it not be from 0-1 and be from 0 to 45 on the y-axis ?

Comment: You can multiply this distribution with any value to shift it up or downwards, say 45, or the current values of every node. The default Gaussian / normal distribution only puts constraints on the width, not necessary the height. Your picture looks more like a sinusoidal wave than a normal distribution.

Comment: The picture tries to remove the zeros between the points and is very idealized, with this the form the code all shift up by 45, but they don't seem to vary i.e. 24 and 27 points in height. Any idea on mimicking beta/landau functions instead of Gaussian?

Comment: In the `create` function, this line `distribution = np.exp(-4 * np.log(2) * distance / fwhm ** 2)` determines the distribution. And `distance = sum((ax - ax_center) ** 2 for ax_center, ax in zip(center, self.axis))` determines the distance. Therefore you have to remove the squared distance and change the distribution to your preferred `beta` or `landau` function. For example see Wikipedia [landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_distribution) and then the CF (cumulative function) for the formula that you have to implement.

Comment: i tried doing this ```from scipy.special import gamma```

Comment: ```distribution = (gamma(a+b)*distance**(a-1)*(1-distance)**(b-1))/(gamma(a)*gamma(b))```

Comment: But this did not give out any plots and gave off multiple errors of the shape of the data frame  of this type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67244021/generating-a-series-of-beta-signal-peeks-on-one-plot can we produce such a plot as described in the question(from the link)?